# Code giving SEG FAULT only when the class is being derived!

Tags: c++

I am unable to find out the bug in the below code which i had written[Not for any purpose though].

```
#include < iostream >
#include < cstdlib >

using namespace std;


class Base{
public:
        Base(){cout << "Base class constructor" << endl;}
        void funv() {};
        ~Base(){cout << "Base class destructor" << endl;} ;
};

class Derived:public Base{
public:
        char *ch;
        Derived():ch(new char[6]()){}
        ~Derived(){
                cout << "before" << endl;
                delete [] ch;
                ch = NULL;
                cout << "after" << endl;
        }
};

int main(){

        Derived * ptr = new Derived;

        //memcpy(ptr -> ch,"ar\0",4); // Works when class Derived is derved from base and also when not derived from base

        ptr -> ch = const_cast < char* >("ar0");  // Works only when class Derived is not derived from class Base

        cout << ptr -> ch[1] << endl;

        ptr -> funv();

        delete ptr;

        return 0;
}
```

I have commented on the suspected lines of the code.

I am using sun Studio 12.

Comment: -1: No idea why you thought this would be safe.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yes, after more than 3 years of asking this question, even I now dont know why I thought it would be safe :). Thanks for bringing it to notice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an **Undefined behavior**. It will cause problem in any case, whether you derive it or not.
When you assign a `const char*` to a `char*` like below:

```
ptr -> ch = const_cast < char* >("ar0");
```

That means, you are assigning a character string which is defined in non-heap segment (mostly in data segment). One should only `delete` memory which was allocated on **heap segment**.

Also, above assignment statement is executed, it will **leak memory** pointed by `ch` earlier. One way to avoid such problem is to declare the variable as,

```
private: char* const ch;
```

As soon as you try assigning something to `ch`, it will give compilation error. So that it will make you write wrapper to assign `ch` and there you can take care of deallocation.

Comment: Yes. you are right. But why I am not getting a seg fault when i am not deriving from base class? Or is it due to UB i am not getting any seg fault ?

Comment: yes it is due to Undefined Behavior. You might get segmentation fault in some other compiler. But it's a pure UB.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a serious problem with understanding the meaning of Undefine Behavior.

## Undefined Behavior doesn't necessarily mean a segfault

sorry for shouting but this is a very importan point.

Undefined behavior means, like the name suggest, "undefined". This means that you don't know what is going to happen. Actually a segfault is the best thing that you can hope for... but unfortunately 90% of UB in C++ is just silent.

The application will run normally and will even give you the results you expect. Everything will be fine... until of course the demo day when in front of an hundred people the application will crash badly just for the fun of getting your stunned face on youtube.

Undefined behavior is one of the reasons for which learning C or C++ by experimentation is a bad idea. When you make an error in C++ the language is not going to help you... the silent assumption is basically that you will not make any error... and if you are learning the language this is of course a very difficult requirement to match.

Undefined behavior is also the reason for which putting too much hope in the test suite when writing in C or C++ is also a bad idea. In these languages (and in other languages where UB is present) it is a very dumb approach to write code without too much thinking (therefore letting bugs in) and then hoping to remove them later. While this idea of saving thinking time first and trading it with debugging time later is IMO a bad approach in general (the cost/effort of bug removal will always be higher), in languages that allow UB this is a true suicide because bugs can hide also behind non-deterministic behavior.

Clearly I'm not saying that testing is a bad idea... it's of course a great one (basically a must-have if you want to keep a refactoring possibility) but **only** if it's not used as an excuse to lower the attention you put when writing the code.

You should basically avoid to confuse what is an error (i.e. UB) with what is a crash (i.e. the segfault). Crash are friends... and you want to have as many possible crashes as you can, because a crash is a signal that an error is present. To add more possible crash points for example you should use assertions... a segfault is just an assertion automatically placed by the environment but you need more. When you have a crash then you know there is an error and you can start looking for it. Unfortunately when you don't have a crash it doesn't mean that there are no errors... it simply means that no bug fell in the traps you've prepared for them.

A piece of code can compile fine (zero errors and zero warnings), it can pass the whole test suite... but can still be at the same time incorrect. This is true of course even in higher level languages where it has been decided that the performance price to pay to avoid UB was worth runtime checks (e.g. Java) but an higher logical level. UB in C and C++ makes things a little harder because of non-determinism.

In your code UB is triggered because you are calling `delete[]` on a pointer that wasn't obtained with a call to `new ... []` (a string literal). This may or may not of course generate a segfault.

Your code also has some other legal but very questionable parts:

1. The base class destructor is not virtual. You are not destroying a derived object using a pointer to base, so this is legal, but none the less it's a bad idea. If a class is meant to be derived then the destructor should be virtual.
2. The derived class defines a destructor, but no copy constructor and no assignment operator. [These three methods should always go together](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C++_programming%29): either you define none of them or you define (or at least declare) all three of them. The reason is that these three methods are automatically created by the compiler if they are not present and it's quite unlikely that the automatically generated code is correct in one case but not in the others. In your code for example if someone makes a copy of the derived object using `Derived *der2 = new Derived(*der1);` the pointer to the dynamically allocated memory will be just copied and possibly deallocated twice (once for each of the two objects destroyed); in case of an assignment with `*der2 = *der1;` instead you will have a potential double-deallocation in addition to a memory leak. It may make sense to forbid copy constructor and assigment for a class, but in this case the common idiom is to declare those methods private and leaving them not implemented (this will give a compile error if someone else tries to use them, and a link error if a method uses them by mistake).

Comment: well written but from the answers which I have got it is the 10% that have come into picture i.e "Seg Fault due to UB". Any other possible flaw you see other than assigning string literal to a char pointer to which memory has been allocated? (I think the flaw is big enaough...but still :) )

Comment: If you think that the absence of a virtual destructor is an error here you are wrong. Virtual destructors are of course always a good idea for classes meant to be derived... but if you never destroy a derived object using a pointer to base this is not a language requirement.

Comment: I've edited by adding another couple of comments about your C++ code.

Comment: "Derived *der2 = new Derived(*der1);" :: My constructor doesnt take any parameter and from what i know on doing "Derived der2 = der1;" there will be shallow copying due to copy constructor. or Doing this "Derived der2 = *der1;"

Comment: This is exactly the problem. After copy construction or assignment the two objects will have the same value in the `char *` member `ch` so both of the objects will call `delete[]` on the same pointer (and this is also UB). The general rule says that if you have for example a destructor then probably shallow copy or shallow assignment is not correct (but it's what C++ will create automaticall if you don't write your own version).

Answer (score -1):

```
memcpy(ptr -> ch,"ar\0",4);
```

`memcpy` copys the contents from source buffer to the destination buffer your pointer `ptr->ch` points to.

```
ptr -> ch = const_cast < char* >("ar0");
```

You're reassigning the value to the pointer itself. This is dangerous because you have no way to get the original buffer on heap anymore. That's a memory leak. Also, in your destructor you delete this pointer which now doesn't points to a buffer on heap. It's undefined.

Comment: Vote down without leaving a comment is so not professional. No reasons?

Comment: I am performing only one action at a time . Not doing both at same time. For test puposes i leave one of the two statements commented.

Comment: @Eric, I think someone might have voted down because of your reference to `memcpy`; that line is commented in the code; so it doesn't have any relevance. I suggest, you should remove that line from your answer.

Comment: @ArunMu, I don't think you understand the two lines of your code correctly. Though you comment out "memcpy" line, you are asking us why the second one doesn't work in both case while the first one does. That shows to me that you don't have a clear distinction of them. So here is my answer, to clarify them for you.

Comment: @iammilind, No. If OP had known the difference between "memcpy(ptr->ch..)" and "ptr->ch=..", he wouldn't have used the pointer that way, which caused the memory leak and undefined behavior eventually.

Comment: @Eric: I do understand the difference between both statements. My question was "why a segfault when the class is  derived but not when class is not derived"